# wordpress statistic of wp api

Tags: wordpress, angular, ionic2, wp-api

I'm aware that there are tons of plugins that can track user behaviour in a wordpress site. Those plugins can track how many views does a blog post has.

Currently, I am developing an ionic app where the contents come from wordpress served by using wp-api. And I make it in a such a way the users can only access my content only through the mobile app. Now, my problem is, can these plugins track how many views a blog post has that is views through the app?

If there's plugin that able to perform such task, please recommend it to me

Thank you

Comment: Like Google Analytics?

Comment: @DanWhite can google analytic tracks views of a post served by wp-api?

Comment: AFAIK, Google analitics require a browser rendering some javascript code you put in your page (more or less, it works also without JS, but anyway require browser making an HTTP request to Goolge). in a WP-api scenario you cannot rely on this.

Comment: @GianPaolo that's what I've been telling my supervisor, but he insist there's a way to track. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: maybe there is, but not using the "standard" way that analytics use. WP-APi return data to its client, not HTML code. so it all depends on what you ionic client application handle the data it gets. It maybe can post an HTTP request to google saying somehow "hi mr google, someone has just loaded my post n#xxx". But implementing this is far over what I know about this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the Jetpack plugin from the creators of WordPress? Their Site Stats feature does break down views by posts.

Comment: Jetpack can only track views from the website as far as I know. I need an option where wordpress can track any activity my users do in the app. For that to happen, my app should be able to send some data to wordpress. But for now, I don't know any methods to perform such task.